# Python Numpy Matrix generation error

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to generate a matrix to 15x15, 16x16 and 17x17 with the 500 group. But when I run my code I got only 15x15 matrix. I checked the value of the dimmension too. There is no problem with that, too. My code as in below:

```
import numpy as np
M = 0
N = 15
for i in range(0,3):
    # I must generate matrix with in the range of N with 500 groups.
    # It must be with the dimension of 15x15, 16x16, 17x17
    while M < 500:
        # first I generate matrix in the size of NxN
        main_matrix = np.random.random_integers(-4, 4, size=(N, N))
        # later I created symmetric matrix
        sym_matrix = main_matrix + main_matrix.T
        # I assigned zero to all dioganal elements
        for a in range(N):
            sym_matrix[a][a] = 0
            print(sym_matrix)
        M += 1
    #print(N)
    N += 1
```

Comment: Do you get only one 15x15 matrix or do you get 3 times a 15x15 matrix?

Comment: Not at all clear what you're trying to do here. Can you please clarify the first sentence a little more? You say you're trying to create a matrix with three different sizes. Do you mean you want to create three matrices? What is the overall shape you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No, actually I need to generate overall 1500 matrix with 3 groups (500, 500, 500). Each group of matrix must have different sizes: 15x15, 16x16, 17x17

Comment: @Kev1n91 I get 1500 15x15 matrix. The problem is it must me 500 - 15x15, 500 16x16, 500 17x17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot to put M back to 0

```
import numpy as np
N = 15
for i in range(0,3):
    # I must generate matrix with in the range of N with 500 groups.
    # It must be with the dimension of 15x15, 16x16, 17x17
    M = 0
    while M < 500:
        # first I generate matrix in the size of NxN
        main_matrix = np.random.random_integers(-4, 4, size=(N, N))
        # later I created symmetric matrix
        sym_matrix = main_matrix + main_matrix.T
        # I assigned zero to all dioganal elements
        for a in range(N):
            sym_matrix[a][a] = 0
            print(sym_matrix)
        M += 1
    #print(N)
    N += 1
```

You may want to change the while to a for loop, so that this error does not happen again. This code should then look like this

```
import numpy as np
M = 0
N = 15
for i in range(0,3):
    # I must generate matrix with in the range of N with 500 groups.
    # It must be with the dimension of 15x15, 16x16, 17x17

    for M in range(0,500):
        # first I generate matrix in the size of NxN
        print(N)
        main_matrix = np.random.random_integers(-4, 4, size=(N, N))
        # later I created symmetric matrix
        sym_matrix = main_matrix + main_matrix.T
        # I assigned zero to all dioganal elements
        for a in range(N):
            sym_matrix[a][a] = 0
            print(sym_matrix)
        M += 1

    print(N)
   # print(M)
    N += 1
```

Comment: OMG yes. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

While Loop only runs once because your not setting M=0 when while exited.

Fixed Code:

```
import numpy as np
M = 0
N = 15
for i in range(0,3):
    # I must generate matrix with in the range of N with 500 groups.
    # It must be with the dimension of 15x15, 16x16, 17x17
    while M < 500:
        # first I generate matrix in the size of NxN
        main_matrix = np.random.random_integers(-4, 4, size=(N, N))
        # later I created symmetric matrix
        sym_matrix = main_matrix + main_matrix.T
        # I assigned zero to all dioganal elements
        for a in range(N):
            sym_matrix[a][a] = 0
            print(sym_matrix)
        M += 1
    #print(N)
    M = 0
    N += 1
```

Comment: Also random_integers is deprecated use randint instead.